# Dependable drop down list using ajax in codeigniter is not working

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, mysqli

Im trying to make a dependable dropdownlist using ajax in codeigniter. I used a code..but its not working.. the values are not appended to the dropdownlist. Retrieving data from database to first dropdown list is working perfectly. First Dropdown list works fine...but i want to make dependable dropdown list subcategory based on category using ajax

CONTROLLER::

```
public function pdview()
{
   $this->load->helper('url');
   $this->load->helper('form'); 
   $this->load->model('AjaxpModel');
   $data['cnames'] = $this->AjaxpModel->getcat();
   $this->load->view('pd',$data);
}

public function getsubcaty()
{
   $postData = $this->input->post();
   $this->load->model('AjaxpModel');
   $data = $this->AjaxpModel->getsubcategory($postData);
   echo json_encode($data);
}
```

View::

```
Category Name :   <select name="category" id="category">
                  <option value="">Select</option>
                  <?php
                     foreach($cnames as $catn){
                            echo "<option value='".$catn['catname']."'>".$catn['catname']."</option>";
                     }
                  ?>
                  </select><br><br>
Subategory Name :
                  <select name="subcategory" id="subcategory">
                     <option value="">Select</option>
                  </select><br><br>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

var baseURL= "<?php echo base_url();?>";

$(document).ready(function(){
   // Category Change
   $('#category').change(function(){
      var cat = $(this).val();
      // AJAX request
      $.ajax({
         url:'<?=base_url()?>index.php/Ajaxuser/getsubcaty',
         method: 'post',
         data: {cat:cat},
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(response){
            $('#subcategory').find('option').not(':first').remove();
               // Add options
               $.each(response,function(index,data){

                  $('#subcategory').append('<option value="'+data['subcatname']+'">'+data['subcatname']+'</option>');

               });
            }
      });
   });
});
```

Model:::

```
public function getcat()
{
   $this->load->database();
   $result=$this->db->select('cid,catname')->from('catc')->get()->result_array(); 
   $cname=array();
   foreach($result as $r)
   {
      $catname[$r['catname']] = $r['catname'];
   }
   $catname[''] = 'Select '; 
   return $catname; 
}

function getsubcategory($postData){
   $response = array();

   // Select record
   $this->db->select('scid,subcatname');
   $this->db->from('scatc');
   $this->db->where('catname', $postData['cat']);
   $q = $this->db->get();
   $response = $q->result_array();
   return $response;
}
```

Comment: Hey, check on your Controller under `getsubcaty` method, change `$postData = $this->input->post();` to `$postData = $this->input->post('cat');` and also on your model `getsubcategory` function, do not store the returning data to array, just use **`return $q->result()`** so that it is in *Object form* data that can be formally encoded.

Comment: just echo all the options from server side and .html() at front side is easy way.

Comment: @Roshan i changed according to u said..but... the value still not retrieved into dropdownlist:(

Comment: @DevsiOdedra  I tried that too

Comment: so you get result from server or not?

Comment: check console error & keep console.log(response) in ajax success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all check if your `base_url()` is  defined properly.

As you followed my steps on comment section, I think I see the issue on your JS,

You can try this one:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

            // Category Change
            $('#category').change(function(){
                var cat = $(this).val();
                // AJAX request
                $.ajax({
                    url:'<?=base_url()?>index.php/Ajaxuser/getsubcaty',
                    method: 'post',
                    data: {cat:cat},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response){

                var $el = $("#subcategory");

                 $el.empty();
                 $("#subcategory").val('');
                 $el.append($("<option></option>")
                        .attr("value", '')
                        .attr("hidden",'')
                        .text('Select Subcategory'));

                $.each(response, function(index, data){
                    $el.append('<option 
                    value="'+data.subcatname+'">'+data.subcatname+'</option>')
                });

                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Let's see what you got there after trying this.

> On your `getsubcategory` model you forgot to load the database. It should be like this:

```
   $this->load->database();
```

> On same model function, `$postData[cat]` must be only `$postData` because you are not passing an array data from your controller otherwise you will be having Illegal string offset error.

**EDIT:**
Since we've figured out that the problem is `base_url()`

Configure if the helper `'url'` is loaded, you can set it on `application/config/autoload.php`.

[image: Configure url helper on autoload]

and you must define it to know what exactly the value of `base_url().`

You can set it on `application/config/config.php`.

**To test if the `base_url()` is working, try to echo base_url().**

[image: Configurations]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187977/discussion-between-roshan-and-hhhhhh).